# Slide JS - Instead of bullet pagination.. need to use div container

Tags: jquery

We need to modify existing slide JS plugin (should not use any other plugins) to work from default to modified version. Default version is already using on other pages.

Instead of default bullet navigation, have to use div container like in attached screenshot. when that div clicked, it have to show index of that slide like happening in default function.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content--carousel">
<div class="slides-item">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1120x632">
        <span class="gradient-bg"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="slides-item">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1120x632">
        <span class="gradient-bg"></span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>

//Thumbnail like div container 
<div class="carousel-thumb">
<div class="carousel-thumb--content">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="carousel-thumb--image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/63x63">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-thumb--text">
            <div class="carousel-thumb--title">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
            <div class="carousel-thumb--desc">Ut fringilla augue eget quam lacinia</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="carousel-thumb--content active">
   <a href="#">
        <div class="carousel-thumb--image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/63x63">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-thumb--text">
            <div class="carousel-thumb--title">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
            <div class="carousel-thumb--desc">Ut fringilla augue eget quam lacinia</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: which is the existing JS plugin?? Any link to that!! You might need to modify plugin!! Or Are these images dynamically added??

Comment: Hi.. plugin http://www.slidesjs.com/ .. These images are added dynamically from backend.  instead of bullet slide.. we need to use div container to see background image & content of clicked thumbnail div container.

Comment: Ok I got your point!! Can you show how you looping the controls to render in the html and what backend you are using?

Comment: The whatever html you prepared meets the requirement right??

Comment: yes.. HTML strucure is finalised one.. Only thing.. dont know which script to add to make this as clickable and work like default bullet.

Comment: Any solution bro?? I cant able to make this container to show correct image based on thumbnail container clicked

Comment: Just go through **[this link](http://codepen.io/Kopepasah/pen/nzoyI)** and **[this link](http://thinsoldier.github.io/externals/slidesjs/examples/thn-thumbnails-2/)**. Hope you'l get some idea.. Since much detail hasn't been provided here I cannot help you much